# htaccess and MVC routing

Tags: model-view-controller, .htaccess, routes

Well i started coding a mini MVC base that I can just use on client websites, which also uses the same type of router class as CakePHP. I currently have the url display like this:

`http://localhost/mvc/index.php?page=blog/viewall`

Which gets the controller and tells it the function, just like CakePHP index(), view(), and so on.

Now, I'm not sure how I can make the url look like this with .htaccess

`http://localhost/mvc/blog/viewall`

I was trying to add this in the .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your redirect rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mvc/index.php/.*
RewriteRule ^/mvc/(.*) /mvc/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you pls paste your .htaccess file content here?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mvc/index.php/.*
RewriteRule ^/mvc/(.*) /mvc/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Can u change RewriteRule to 

RewriteRule ^/mvc/(.*) /mvc/index.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]

and try again.

If still doesn't work I would suggest commenting out RewriteCond line above and see if you get infinite redirects in your browser or not.