# A Dynamic website using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am a beginner PHP programmer. I searched google for a "Dynamic PHP website tutorials". I found some stuff. They use `$_GET` variable to make the website dynamic, so the URL's appear like this:

- example.com/?page=home
- example.com/?page=about
- example.com/?page=Downloads
  and so on...

But most of the dynamic websites that I found on the internet has links like this:

- example.com
- example.com/about
- example.com/download and so on....

So how do they do so ?? Have they got folders for all the catogories ?? And Also some websites have article URLs (eg : example.com/articles/posts/2010/article1.php). It would be a reall mess if they've got folders for all items. If not then How ?? Can someone give an example please ?

Comment: this is all about `.htaccess`. you also have to read about `.htaccess`

Comment: that is called, URL rewriting. the webserver will map that pretty url to a classic GET/POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using apache then read: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If you're using IIS then read: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `$_GET` variable, it must be in the query string (or being routed through some other means that isn't 'default').

For example, the URLs you're using would become.

```
example.com/?page=home
example.com/?page=about
example.com/?page=Downloads
```

Additionally, you can rewrite URLs using the .htaccess file (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in page routing.

[htaccess and MVC routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332030/htaccess-help-with-mvc-routing) may start you down the correct path :)

Comment: that's what i meant ! but is it the only way ?

Comment: In my opinion it's the the easiest way to hide the page routing from the user.

Answer (score 1):

To echo everyone else, it's called a url rewite. 
For example, the url

```
http://example.com/index.php?ext=blog&cat=news&date=12122012
```

can be rewritten as

```
http://example.com/blog/news/12-12-2012
```

This isn't automatic, it requires defining the patterns used for understanding the new URL in a file called .htaccess which usually resides in the servers root directory. Note that the preceding '.' in the filename makes it a hidden file.

When I was first getting used to PHP i found the site http://phpbuilder.com a great help. They have a lot of articles, and a forum that is fairly nice to noobies. http://devshed.com is a good site too, and has a large amount of information on subjects outside of PHP.

Comment: Note that whats happining is that the server recives the URL _example.com/blog/news/12-12-2012_ and rewrites it so that PHP sees _example.com/index.php?ext=blog&cat=news&date=12122012_ and is able to access the $_GET vars, such as $_GET['ext'] and $_GET['task'] in the url above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that affect with folders, but most use rewrites ([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). It's a bit too broad of a subject to go in to here, but if you just search for rewrite tutorials you'll find some pretty quickly.

The $_GET is only to get variables from the URL. While this can be used to make sites dynamic, this is a technique which is usually frowned upon.

With rewrites, you basically have a URL like /about, but the rewrite tells your server something like "act like this is actually ?page="about"), which you then use the $_GET to process.

Answer (score 0):

Being PHP beginner I will not urge you to use `.htaccess`, As you will need to learn lot many things before you proceed further. You have 2 option to send a request one is `GET` and `POST`. You can get more information about same on internet.

Also you have an option to start your `dynamic website` using `CMS` and I will recommend you to use `wordpress`. CMS will have some `in-built function` which will help you to do your work faster. Also using their `control panel you can update the URL format`.

I will also urge you to go step by step and follow every tutorial that you will find on internet.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you have to use `.htaccess` file and have to load `mod_rewrite` in your `apache` server.

In you root directory create file named `.htaccess`

Then Write:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And After that call a page

```
my-page.php
```

It will redirected as a `index.php?page=my-page` internally but in browser it will show as `my-page.php`